# Failed to open APK in Rubymotion

Tags: android, rubymotion

I'm getting the following error when running: `bundle exec rake release` on my RubyMotion Android app:

```
ziparchive W 08-24 13:55:26 89539 4680851 Unable to open '~/.rubymotion-android/sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar': No such file or directory
error: failed to open APK: I/O error.
rake aborted!
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the `target_api_version` set:

```
app.target_api_version = "30
```

But I should have set the `api_version` instead:

```
app.api_version = "30"
```